# JMS bridge in WebSphere 7.0

Tags: java, jms, websphere

How can I define a JMS bridge in WebSphere 7.0 application server?

Answer (score 0):

Does the MQ Link capability do what you need? See this [Info Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/welcome_nd.html) article.